# Installing LibSVM for Matlab on a Mac

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion, XCode 5.0.2, and Matlab_R2013a. I'm trying to install LibSVM in these environments. I already installed Command Line Tools and I am trying to "make" file (go to unpacked folder of LibSVM on my Desktop, go to folder matlab and run "make"). However, I receive a fatal error "mex.h file not found". Would you please hint me at the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Makefile and use commandline make,  then you need to edit the Makefile and make sure all the setting are correct. By default, some for Mac (in particular MATLABDIR) are commented out.

You should also be able to build by exxecuting the make.m script in Matlab.
If you want to do that, you need to run the following command in Matlab:

```
mex -setup
```

and when prompted select an appropriate **C++** compiler.
 Then you should be able to run `make` in Matlab.